# Dúvidas com banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, data-warehouse

Para que serve o Staging Area? Posso buscar Dados de outros sistemas (bancos diferentes)?

O que é um Data Mart? Ele está vinculado aos setores ou processos de negócio da organização?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

há muito material sobre isso na internet, pesquise sobre **Data Warehouse**, **mineração de dados** e **business intelligence (BI)** . é uma área muito interessante para se estudar e aplicar.

resumindo, é a extração de dados de uma base maior, que você usa para alguma outra finalidade.

mas vamos lá :

**Staging Area** é um repositório de dados, digamos que temporário, para ajudar você montar o Data Warehouse. ali você faz o tratamento como extração e limpeza de dados. muitos fazem essa extração por meio do ETL (Extração, Tratamento e Limpeza).

**Data Mart** é um repositório de dados, sub-conjunto de dados de um Data warehouse. Imagine a seguinte situação. Um empresa tem durante um ano registrado em sua base dados todos as informações referentes a vendas e faturamento. Então ela quer realizar uma previsão de vendas para o próximo ano.
Com base nessas informações, eu posso criar um data mart, extraindo e agrupando e limpando essas informações para que os vendedores façam uma previsão de vendas. Com base nisso posso gerar um ferramenta de BI, para que os gestores acompanhem o andamento durante o ano dessa previsão.